# update status of boolean in django based on courses id

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in `Django`. I am posting some values to front-end which will be changed by the user. After being modified by the user, the back-end is creating duplicates of ids. Can anyone please help with this issue?

**I want to update those checked values( [true to false] or [false to true]) in Django avoiding duplicates**

Here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=True)
    courseid = models.IntegerField(default=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CourseSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('checked', 'value', 'courseid')
```

**views.py**

```
class CourseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CourseSerializers
    queryset = Course.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: use HTTP PATCH request

Comment: could you please tell where should i use that http patch method in my code

Comment: You do not have change in code. You just need to make the request using HTTP PATCH. You can use postman for testing. https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#selecting-request-methods